# How to check serial connection between 2 Linux PCs

Tags: linux, serial-port, connection, fedora20

I need to connect 2 linux PCs via serial port. I used serial connector cable (null modem cable) to connect 2 linux PCs. But now how can I establish the connection  I mean how can I test whether they are connected or not. Can anybody Please let me know the procedure.. I have tried screen command and when i run

> screen /dev/ttyS0

This command is just opening new screen and i cant do anything on that new screen.

Am using Fedora-20 with kernel version 3.* in one PC and another one with Fedora-27 kernel version is 4.13

Comment: `cat /dev/ttys0` at one end and `echo wtf > /dev/ttys0` at the other.

Comment: what is expected output it should print that wtf message in that system where I executed cat command right?? but this is not printing that message ... what went wrong ...

Comment: Insufficient information to answer that. Cable not connected? Cable not wired properly? Either com port not configured correctly? 8-N-1 is the standard configuration. etc. etc. Google is your friend. This question is probably off topic here.

Comment: Cable is connected, and it is wired properly.. and i haven't done any configuration I am searching but did not get correct procedure .. any ways thanks for your suggestion if you know about configuration please share.

Comment: minicom is a tool that will help you. run it at both ends, and use it to configure your ports.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi finally i found solution to my problem  Using [this_link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/connect-soekris-single-board-computer-using-minicom.html).

at both ends tried below steps:

1) `yum install minicom`

2) Then I configured minicom using `minicom -s` then using down arrow selected **serial port setup**
then **pressed A** from keyborad to change that **serial device** from

> /dev/modem

to

> /dev/ttyS0

press enter and chose **save as dfl** option then **exit from minicom**

After these configuration steps executed the commands suggested by @Niall Cosgrove

at one end executed `cat /dev/ttyS0`

at other end executed `echo hello > /dev/ttyS0`

finally i got hello message from one pc to other end using serial port:)